# Controlling electronic components with USB?

Tags: python, usb, libusb

I want to try something that I imagine is somewhat simple. I want to have a USB cable with an LED on it, and a python script that would have 2 possible arguments: "on" and "off". This would toggle the LED on and off (obviously). So, anyone who knows software know which libraries (if not libusb) to use and how to use them, and hardware people, know how I might make said circuit? I don't want to turn the USB's power supply off, I just want to change something in the circuit to disable the LED.

Comment: I assume you don't want a processor to do the usb processing on the other side? I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB is a serial protocol; you can't just set it "on" or "off", the way you used to be able to set a parallel port pin.

You need something (ie an embedded microprocessor) on the far end; the computer talks to the microprocessor which drives the LED.

Take a look at an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/); they are cheap, readily available, and easy to use.

**Edit:** try the [Teensy](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/) - completely Arduino-compatible, $16, just over an inch square, has a USB port and 25 I/O pins.

Comment: 1. Thanks for the reply, and 2. Is there a way to connect to this with Python, or would I have to use the Arduino language?

Comment: The Arduino programming environment is a subset of C; with a little work you can also program it directly in C (using WinAVR or avr-gcc). On the host computer, you can use Processing (based on Java) or any language that lets you talk to a serial port - this includes Python via the PySerial module.